# how to enable cookies/javascript

Tags: java, selenium, testing

I'm trying to create a scenario on chegg.com
but it seems that it is programmed to detect automation tools

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KRhix.png)

is there a way to enable javascript and cookies before and preconfig or at least a way to not trigger this issue?

Answer (score 0):

```
var options = new ChromeOptions();
            options.AddArguments("--enable-javascript");
options.AddUserProfilePreference("profile.cookie_controls_mode", 0);
            driver = new ChromeDriver("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application", options);

            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(loginUrl);
```

Try the above for javascript and cookies enabled. The code is in c#. You may try the desired option in your own programming language.